# How can i fix image width

Tags: javascript

Here is a script for blog auto read more. I have given value in script for img thumb height and width but it is not applying it on my blog. anyone help me..

Here is my blog link.

[My Blogger Tricks](http://www.myblogger-tricks.com)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var thumbnail_mode = &quot;no-float&quot; ;
summary_noimg = 430;
summary_img = 340;
img_thumb_height = 100;
img_thumb_width = 100;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){
if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
{
var s = strx.split("<");
for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){
s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length);
}
}
strx = s.join("");
}
chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2;
while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++;
strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1);
return strx+'...';
}

function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
var div = document.getElementById(pID);
var imgtag = "";
var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
var summ = summary_noimg;
if(img.length>=1) {
imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 5px 5px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>';
summ = summary_img;
}

var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
div.innerHTML = summary;
}

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is CSS rule you have there setting image height to auto, see below:

```
.post img {height:auto;}
```